# DSL to append Strings to List

Tags: scala, dsl

This is my first attempt at a DSL in scala :

```
object ListOfStringsDsl extends App {

  object Commands {

    val l: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer();

    def and(s: String) = {
      l += s;

      this
    }

    override
    def toString = l.mkString(",")
  }

  println(Commands and("test") and("test2") toString)
}
```

This prints :

```
test,test2
```

This is the expected output. But I want to simplify how the output is created, so instead of `println(Commands and("test") and("test2") toString)` to output commands how to use :

Want to be able to use :

```
println(Commands "test" and "test2" toString)
```

How to achieve this in Scala ?

Comment: The and should work just find, calling the toString might require to import this language feature: import language.postfixOps You probably shouldn't implement a DSL like this using side-effects though. "asd" and "foo" looks very much like an expression, not something that modifies a global object Commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have succeeded with implicit

```
  case class Commands(val list: List[String]) {
    def and(that: String) = Commands(that :: list)
  }
  implicit def command(cmd: String) = Commands(cmd :: Nil)
  println("run1" and "wait")
```

I think that implicits are essential component of DSL.